# Exception type: TaskCanceledException -On startup File -WebAPI

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, api, rest

We are facing very wired situation on the WEBAPI Project Created, the production we getting teh error on event Viewer window "

on the startup File we are implemented Microsoft Qwin , with the following code

var accessTimeOut = 60;
var allowInsecureHttp = false;

```
            if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["accessTokenTimeout"] != null)
                accessTimeOut = Int32.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["accessTokenTimeout"]);
            var isHarbingerFlag = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IsHarbingerDev"];
            if (isHarbingerFlag != null && isHarbingerFlag == "true")
                allowInsecureHttp = true;

            var OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
            {
                AllowInsecureHttp = allowInsecureHttp,
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),

                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(0, accessTimeOut, 0),
                Provider = new OwinsAuthorizationServerProvider(),
                RefreshTokenProvider = new RefreshTokenProvider(),
            };

            app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);
            app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthOptions);
            // app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());

            //var properties = new AppProperties(app.Properties);
            //CancellationToken token = properties.OnAppDisposing;

            HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
            WebApiConfig.Register(config);
```

I am not sure what is wrong on the production peek hour my application start logging the error like : xception information:
Exception type: TaskCanceledException
Exception message: A task was canceled.
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.OAuthAuthorizationServerHandler.

Can anybody help me on this ?

Comment: Your post suggests it is working every other hour of the day, so in peek what is the performance metrics of the server like?  I saw a similar timeout message on a task albeit not related to the same service, but was due to a memory leak and server resources were 100% and that was the route issue. Eg, nothing to do with the code in question, but some other code that was badly written, that when under load kept more and more in memory without flushing it.

Comment: Memory leak is not a option !!!...  this is exact expection ...Exception information: 
    Exception type: TaskCanceledException 
    Exception message: A task was canceled.
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)